# Complexity of vertex separator problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Given a graph $\Gamma=(V,E)$ with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$, a *three-partition* is a decomposition of $V$ into a triple $(V_1, S, V_2)$ such that vertices of $V_1$ are only incident to vertices in $V_1$ and $S$ and similar for $V_2$. In other words, by removing the vertices in $S$ from $\Gamma$ one ends up with two disjoint graphs. Let $n=|V|$ and $\beta: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. In its easiest form the *vertex separator problem (VSP)* is to find a triple $(V_1, S, V_2)$ with

1. $(V_1,S,V_2)$ is a three-partition of $\Gamma$.
2. $|V_1|, |V_2|\leq \beta(n)$
3. The three-partition is minimal among all three-partitions satisfying 2., i.e. $|S|\leq |R|$ for all three-partitions $(W_1, R,W_2)$ with $|W_1|, |W_2|\leq \beta(n)$.

It is known that for general graphs and $\beta(n)$ the problem is NP-hard. However, in [Polyhedral VSP](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-005-0574-7) it is stated that for $\beta(n)=n-k$ for some positive integer $k$ the problem is in fact solvable in polynomial time. They give a solution by mapping $\Gamma$ to a bipartite graph $B_\Gamma= ((V_B, V^\prime_B), E_B)$: For each vertex $v\in V$ one has vertices $v_1\in V_B$, $v_2\in V^\prime_B$ and an edge $(v_1,v_2)\in E_B$. For an edge $e=(v, w)\in E$ there are edges $(v_1,w_2)$, $(w_1,v_2)\in E_B$. Solving the VSP on $\Gamma$ with $\beta(n)=n-k$ is now equivalent to finding an independent set $I$ in $B_\Gamma$ such that $|V_B\cap I|, |V_B^\prime \cap I| \leq n-k$. The claim is that such an independent set can be found in $\mathcal{O}(n^3n^k)$ time, but it isn't said how an algorithm for this looks like.

**Question 1:** Is the claim obvious and if so how does an algorithm for this look like? I thought maybe this is related to Koenig's theorem: A maximal independent set is the complement of a minimal vertex cover (in the set of vertices). Then by Koenig's theorem finding a minimal vertex cover on a bipartite graph is equivalent to finding a maximum matching which can be done in polynomial time. However, due to the condition $|V_B\cap I|, |V_B^\prime \cap I|\leq n-k$ the independent set $I$ doesn't need to be maximal in the first place I think.

**Question 2:** Formulating the VSP in terms of an independent set of a bipartite graph can be done in general. What goes wrong for a polynomial time algorithm for general $\beta(n)$?